# MariaDB 10.3.28 slow performance on CentOS 8 Server

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a server running CentOS 8 with apache, php-fpm, and mariadb.
The last one is giving problems to me.

I tried to import a database of a site into phpmyadmin with the apposite interface and also with mysql command.

The test with interface has been as slow as the timeout of apache (600s) giving to me gateway timeout. The test with mysql command has taken over 6 minutes!

The dump was something like 2MB so it is really unacceptable.

Do you know something I could change in configuration in order to solve this situation?

Already tried this in /etc/my.cnf but nothing happened:

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mariadb/slow-query.log

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 8M
query_cache_size = 512M

max_connections = 500

tmp_table_size= 768M
max_heap_table_size= 768M

thread_cache_size = 12


join_buffer_size = 12M
```

The hardware of the machine I think it shouldn't be a problem, anyway:

- 4 cpu
- 5028 MB ram

Comment: you have enabled the slow log **slow_query_log = 1** ! Have you take a look into this file **/var/log/mariadb/slow-query.log**

Comment: you have not set **innodb_buffer_pool_size** insert **innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G**  to the initfile, but the file you are posted iss missig some entrys. see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size and find a default configuration

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thank for the comments! yes I put that slow_query_log copying a configuration file of someone else because I was literally losing my mind. I've seen that file and it's full of junk!! Should I delete it?

Comment: @BerndBuffen I think innodb_buffer_pool_size could be a good tip. While I was waiting I tried to set it to 2 GB and now it seems slow but not as much as before. I will try to set 3G and see how it is, obv I can't set it as much as the RAM right?

Comment: when you Install MariaDB there is a default config. please use this config. and then you can change some values in it

Comment: @BerndBuffen sorry, are you sure? When I opened for the first time the config file it was all comments except !include_dir etc.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (Or provide what Wilson asked for.)

Comment: What did the slowlog tell you about the slow load?  (cf pt-query-digest)

Answer (score 0):

yes, the individual configurations are in subdirectories. take a look at the subdirs of / etc / mysql e.g. ./mariadb.conf.d